# Find all s-t node cuts in directed (or undirected) graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I need to find all the possible *node* cuts in an s-t graph.
It is a directed graph, but finding the cuts for the undirected graph could be enough (I can filter them afterwards).

Networkx provides functions as:

- [all_node_cuts](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.kcutsets.all_node_cuts.html)

but it is not implemented for directed graphs (no problem) and *it does not consider s-t graphs*, so the solution is not useful in my case (at least for cut sets in which source S is included by the function).

I tried to implement the combinatorial approach (check all the possible combinations of nodes) and it works but is extremely inefficient, starting from graphs with more than 10 nodes the execution time is too large.

I tried to check if it's possible to modify network functions like [minimum_st_node_cut](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.cuts.minimum_st_node_cut.html) but did not succeded and I don't know if it possible to list all the possible cuts.

I could also use any other library if it provides some useful tool for this (even programming language, if needed).

Answer (score 0):

[IGraph](https://igraph.org/python/doc/api/igraph.Graph.html#all_st_cuts) is providing an algorithm, but I cannot evaluate if its computational efficient. For my instance of 93 nodes, it could not find a cut until I stopped it after a few hours. Nevertheless, it works for smaller instances:

```
import numpy as np
from igraph import Graph

# Create adjacancy matrix
adjacency = np.array([  [0,0,0],
                        [0,0,1],
                        [1,0,0],])

iG = Graph.Adjacency((adjacency > 0).tolist())
cuts = iG.all_st_cuts(1,2)
```